# Error when using variable of one class with instance of another

Tags: c#, arrays, class, unity-game-engine

**UPDATE**

```
public class WaypointsClass
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
}


public class MoveEnemy : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private WaypointsClass wp;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;

    void Start () {
       WaypointsClass wp = new WaypointsClass();
        wp.waypoints = new GameObject[waypoints.Length];
        wp.waypoints = waypoints;
print( wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position); **WORKING**
```

}

```
void Update () {
print(wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position);  **NOT WORKING**
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm sure that there is an exception with your second attempt, too. `waypoints` has never been initialized and therefor is `null`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?s=1|8.8322

Comment: I'm working with Unity. waypoints are OK, they DO exist. 
If use Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[0].transform.position; - code is WORKING

Comment: Look at my answer. array is the problem. you must use the new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look very close at this

```
public class WaypointsClass
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
}
```

`WaypointsClass.waypoints` is an **ARRAY**! You must use the `new` keyword to **create** array or stuff like that will happen. `wp.waypoints = new GameObject[waypoints.Length];`

It **should** look like this

```
public class MoveEnemy : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    private WaypointsClass wp;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;

    void Start () {
        WaypointsClass wp = new WaypointsClass();
        wp.waypoints = new GameObject[waypoints.Length]; //This line you missed
        wp.waypoints = waypoints;
        Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position;
```

**EDIT**:

From your comment, you can re-use WaypointsClass `wp` = new WaypointsClass();
by putting WaypointsClass wp outside the `Start` **function** then **initialize** it in the `Start` **function** like below:

```
WaypointsClass wp = null; //Outside (Can be used from other functions)
void Start () {
            wp = new WaypointsClass(); //Init
            wp.waypoints = new GameObject[waypoints.Length]; //This line you missed
            wp.waypoints = waypoints;
            Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working , but if II use in 
     Update () {
     Vector3 startPosition =      wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position;
     }
It fails. Does it mean I must create this thing each time I use Update ???
I thought I must do it only once

Comment: You did WaypointsClass wp = new WaypointsClass(); which is a new instance but you must do thesame for the array. This should solve your problem but post your update code.

Comment: I made an edit. You can re-use it by placing it outside the Start function and then initializing it in the start function. Then you can use it anywhere else. Look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the **GameObject** in the class **WaypointsClass** otherwise you will get a null pointer exception...

and if you do this:

```
wp.waypoints = waypoints;
```

and the waypoints of the right side is a null reference the you will get a NPE too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the waypoints collection in `MoveEnemy` - you're attempting to assign `null` to `wp.waypoints` (I assume you're receiving a `NullReferenceException`...).

Comment: Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[0].transform.position; is WORKING
Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[currentWaypoint].transform.position; Is NOT working.

Answer (score 0):

To try and elaborate a little in case it's not immediately apparent, you've never created any GameObject; the array waypoints is still empty, so when you try to call waypoints[0] (the value of currentWaypoint), the return is null; hence your (assumed) error: "NullReferenceException".

To resolve this, populate your array! Make a whole heap of GameObject and assign them positions.

Comment: The array waypoints is not empty, it's created from unity
 
Vector3 startPosition = wp.waypoints[0].transform.position; is WORKING

Comment: I believe Programmer's reply is the correct one, my apologies! let us know if his solution works.

Comment: @CyberCasper OP is using the access modifier **public** on his gameobjects of arrays, so we should assume that he's setting them in the inspector which is what one normally does in unity.